# "Real" streaming in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, stream

Is there any way to achieve real streaming in PowerShell?

The following statement illustrates what I want:

```
$(Write-Output "one"; Start-Sleep -Seconds 3; Write-Output "two")
```

What I'd expect is:

```
one
<three seconds delay>
two
```

What actually happens is this:

```
<three seconds delay>
one
two
```

So what PowerShell calls "streams" are in fact just lists, but is there some easy way to pass real streams around in PowerShell?

Addition:

I just found out that this does what I'm looking for:

```
function test {
    Write-Output "one";
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 3;
    Write-Output "two";
}

test | % { Write-Host $_ }
```

...but why does `$( ... )` not behave the same way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$()` executes every statement inside it before passing it's output. You can use ScriptBlocks `{}` to have output streamed.

To invoke the ScriptBlock in the current scope, use the dot operator.

```
. {Write-Output "one"; Start-Sleep -Seconds 3; Write-Output "two"}
```

To invoke it in a child scope, use the `&` call operator.

```
& {Write-Output "one"; Start-Sleep -Seconds 3; Write-Output "two"}
```

You can assign a scriptblock to a variable to pass it around.

```
function Show-ExecutingScript ($ScriptBlock) {
    Write-Host "Executing ScriptBlock: `n$ScriptBlock" -Fore Yellow
    & $ScriptBlock
}

$MyCommands = {Write-Output "one"; Start-Sleep -Seconds 3; Write-Output "two"}

Show-ExecutingScript $MyCommands
```

To learn more about ScriptBlocks, check out [about_Script_Blocks](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847893%28v=wps.630%29.aspx)